# Можно ли работать с конкретными входными точками JS в определенных Html?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, pug

Есть два .pug файла (html препроцессор), определенных через HtmlWebpackPlugin. Нужно, чтобы для каждого из них загружались определенные css и js файлы. Возможно ли через входную точку или через API HtmlWebpackPlugin определить какие конкретно стили нужно подгружать на каждую страницу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо создать несколько объектов `HtmlWebpackPlugin` и в каждом их них подключить нужную входную точку. За референс брал [ответ на гитхабе](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/218).

В `webpack.config.js`:

```
entry: {
  'page1': '/path/to/page1.js',
  'page2': '/path/to/page2.js'
},
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
  filename: '[name].bundle.js'
},
```

Там где функция `plugins`:

```
return [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: false,
    template: '...',
    chunks: ['page1'],
    filename: path.join(__dirname, 'build/page1.html'),
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: false,
    template: '...',
    chunks: ['page2'],
    filename: path.join(__dirname, 'build/page2.html'),
  })
]
```